# JQuery function naming dynamically in razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a function in asp.net mvc , in razor template .
I want to naming my function dynamically . but how can I do this ?
this is my function :

```
function ipro-@count() {
                numpro-@count = numpro-@count + 1;
                document.getElementById("numpro-@count").innerHTML = numpro-@count;
            }
```

count is a dynamic number . it does not work for function name . how can I fix it ?

Comment: You can't have a `-` in a function name. What string do you actually want to output as the function name, i.e., how would you like the code to look in the browser if you say View Page Source? Judging by what that function seems to be trying to do I think you're trying to solve the underlying problem the wrong way. Why don't you change the function to accept the number as an argument: `function ipro(num) { document.getElementById("numpro" + num)...`

Comment: When I clean - , it shows me numpro@count as a function name . but @count shoud return a number . for example numpro1 or numpro2 .

Comment: @tsukimi Please show me tsukimi . I'm not professional in jquery .

Comment: I used function ipro(num) , but it does not work ..

Comment: Its not jquery ,its razor, ill put answer below

Comment: _"I used function ipro(num) , but it does not work"_ - Well the rest of the function _and the way you call it_ would need to be changed to work that way. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like so I can't advise further, but as a general principle a generic function that takes the number as an argument is going to be better than repeating the same function over and over...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you do this, need to add the parens around the variable name

```
             function ipro@(count) () {
                numpro@(count) = numpro@(count) + 1;
                document.getElementById("numpro@(count)").innerHTML = numpro@(count);
            }
```

Comment: It shows error because of function naming . function name can't accept - symbol .

Comment: It shows error again . in this solution it returns ipro@count as function name not ipro1 for example .

Comment: Updated the answer , tested it

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple workaround for this concrete situation (when javascript is not too large and complex)

```
@{
    int count = 3;
}
@helper outputFunction(int count)
{
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("function ipro{0}() {{ numpro-{0} = numpro-{0} + 1; document.getElementById('numpro-{0}').innerHTML = numpro-{0}; }}", count));
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        @outputFunction(count);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```